# Remote Execute command - No Wait

Tags: powershell, command-line, invoke-command

This is the code:

```
$remotelastexitcode = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $fdt_server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    Param($Rjava_path, $Rfdt_path, $Rfdt_log_folder, $Rfdt_log_filename)

    Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'start /B $Rjava_path -jar $Rfdt_path -S 1>> $Rfdt_log_folder\$Rfdt_log_filename.txt 2>>&1 & exit 0'";

    $LASTEXITCODE
} -ArgumentList $java_path, $fdt_path, $fdt_log_folder, $fdt_log_filename -ErrorAction Stop

# Force the result to an array, and then test just the last line, which will be
# the last exit code. Anything echoed before that will be ignored.
if (@($remotelastexitcode)[-1] -ne 0) {
    exit 1
}
```

I would like to invoke

```
cmd.exe /c 'start /B $Rjava_path -jar $Rfdt_path -S 1>> $Rfdt_log_folder\$Rfdt_log_filename.txt 2>>&1'
```

on the remote server `$fdt_server`, but not to wait for it to finish.
Basically, I want it to just run it and keep going.

How can I achieve this? I tried using `-AsJob` but does not seem to work.

Comment: try start-process, this command has an wait parameter. I think when you don't use it, the script will continue

Comment: @guiwhatsthat, I tried Start-Command, it started the java process momentarily in the remote computer, then closed, and the Powershell script exit in the local computer. I want the Powershell to exit but keep the java process running in the remote computer after it is launched remotely via the PS script. I also tried using Invoke-Command -Session, does not work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Invoke-WmiMethod does the trick!